# UIAlertController is complete and presented but does not appear during viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have this alert controller setup to appear as soon as the view controller is loaded. However, it does not appear.
I believe I have all the facets covered - title, message, alert style, action button and present... but still does not appear. 
Unsure what I'm missing.

```
  let array = quoteBank()

    print(array.sarcasticQuotes[0].quote)


    let title = "Message"
    let message = array.sarcasticQuotes[0].quote

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(.init(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
   present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Don't try to show the alert in `viewDidLoad`. That's too soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempting to show an alert in `viewDidLoad` is too soon. The view controller isn't displayed yet. Use `viewDidAppear`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Use this if statement to only show the alert once
    if self.isBeingPresented || self.isMovingToParentViewController {
        // show your alert here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much.

Comment: Curious what cases `isBeingPresented` and `isMovingToParentViewController` cover exactly. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth `isBeingPresented` is true when a view controller is being presented via `present`. `isMovingToParentViewController` is called when a view controller is being moved to a parent view controller such as being pushed onto a navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform that on the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The reason behind that is that the view controller's hierarchy will be set after `viewDidLoad` is finished. So by doing this, you're scheduling the presentation of the alert on the main thread to the time the main thread is finished from executing `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: For both of you, why would I need to present an alert controller using dispatch? Also, why would viewDidAppear be better?